# SQL syntax error on Hackerrank challenge - Ollivander's Inventory

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working throught the challenge detailed here:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/harry-potter-and-wands

and have come up with this solution but I'm getting a syntax error message instead or the results I expect. My code:

```
With
  m As (Select
  w.power,
  wp.age,
  Min(w.coins_needed) As min_coins
From
  wands w Join
  wands_property wp
    On wp.code = w.code
Where
  wp.is_evil = 0
Group By
  w.power, wp.age)
Select
w.id,
wp.age,
w.coins_needed,
w.power
From
wands w Join
wands_property wp
On wp.code = w.code
Join m
On m.power = w.power And m.age = wp.age And m.min_coins =
w.coins_needed
Where
wp.is_evil = 0
Order By
w.power Desc,
wp.age Desc,
w.coins_needed Desc
```

The error message from hackerrank:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm As (Select
  w.power,
  wp.age,
  Min(w.coins_needed) As min_coins' at line 2
```

I don't see anything wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure MySQL supports cte's?

Comment: @jarlh Is correct, MySQL doesn't have `WITH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql you should use a select from  (  select  ...   )  and not with

eg

```
select * from  (Select
  w.power,
  wp.age,
  Min(w.coins_needed) As min_coins
From
  wands w Join
  wands_property wp
    On wp.code = w.code
Where
  wp.is_evil = 0
Group By
  w.power, wp.age) t
 ......
```

Looking through your code:

```
Select w.id, wp.age, w.coins_needed, w.power 
From (Select w.power, wp.age, Min(w.coins_needed) As min_coins 
    From wands w Join wands_property wp On wp.code = w.code 
    Where wp.is_evil = 0 Group By w.power, wp.age) m 
Join wands_property wp On wp.code = w.code 
Join m On m.age = wp.age 
And m.power = w.power 
And m.min_coins = w.coins_needed 
Where wp.is_evil = 0 
Order By w.power Desc, wp.age Desc, w.coins_needed Desc
```

You query must be rethinked  because at least you have the e following problems

1. You don't have the table w  because you have used  the related  select naming  m the resulting table so could be
2. you are referring to w.id but you have not a w table in your query
3. you are select a min_coins but you don't  have this column in main select so is not available for where/and clause
4. the w.code  column is not available ( the w table not exist , at least exsite the m  table but you anyway don'thave the code column   )

So you should rebuilt your query  starting from the first part (the subselect in from () clause ) rebuilt your query

Comment: I see. Though I've modified the code and something's still not quite right
`Select
  w.id,
  wp.age,
  w.coins_needed,
  w.power
From
  (Select
    w.power,
    wp.age,
    Min(w.coins_needed) As min_coins
  From
    wands w Join
    wands_property wp
      On wp.code = w.code
  Where
    wp.is_evil = 0
  Group By
    w.power, wp.age) m
Join wands_property wp
    On wp.code = w.code
Join m
    On m.age = wp.age And m.power = w.power And m.min_coins = w.coins_needed
Where
  wp.is_evil = 0
Order By
  w.power Desc,
  wp.age Desc,
  w.coins_needed Desc`

Comment: I have update the answer  with some suggestions .. hope are useful